# Javadoc8 issues in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, javadoc

we use SonarQube Version 5.6.5 with SonarJava Plugin Version 4.4.0.8066 and i am wondering why Sonar is not able to recognize standard javadoc warnings as generated when executing javadoc directly, for instance:

```
warning - Missing closing '}' character for inline tag: "{@link #foo >0)."
warning - @created is an unknown tag.
warning - @return tag has no arguments.
warning - @return tag cannot be used in method with void return type.
warning - @param argument "blah" is not a parameter name.
warning - Tag @see: reference not found: 
warning - Tag @link:illegal character: "62" in "List<Test>"
```

these are quite a lot and quite obvious warnings, so i am really wondering how SonarQube analyses javadoc. it seems pretty obvious that they do not use the javadoc tool itself.

in my research i found out that there have been some bugfixes in the "UndocumentedAPI" Rule, like for instance in Version 4.11:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1377

i could try installing the latest Sonarqube with the latest SonarJava, to check if things have improved, but i would prefer to save the effort for now.

can somebody tell me which versions covers all standard javadoc8 warnings?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarJava does not do these JavaDoc correctness checks.

If you find them essential to your process, then you may want to write custom rules for this. [A tutorial exists](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101) to get you started.

Comment: many thanks for the fast answer, but a bit disappointing. :(
is not the idea to cover all your static code analysis with this one tool? 
is not "JavaDoc correctness" essential for any Java Project?